# Splash screen appears at startup and at reboot after dist-upgrade from Hirsu to Impish

Tags: startup, 21.10

I just finished the (partial) dist-upgrade from Hirsu to Impish.
I start into console text login.
Despite my text login Ubuntu now the splash screen appears at startup *and* before reboot and hides all the text messages.
I ran

```
sudo update-grub2
```

as recommended in some articles to no avail.

Any ideas on how to get back to past behaviour?

Comment: `dist-upgrade`?   Ubuntu isn't Debian, and doesn't use the command `dist-upgrade` to perform *release-upgrades* (*though internally that's part of what is done; but not by user*) so more details may explain why. It reads like you didn't use supported, and QA-tested tools to perform your upgrade.

Comment: Last time I checked `apt dist-upgrade` was the command to upgrade the distribution,  is it not anymore? Anyway, I started the upgrade process from the GUI.

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade packages within the same release (but leaves some packages behind).  `apt-get dist-upgrade` performs the upgrade including steps `upgrade` misses - but in Ubuntu that's within the same release. There is a `do-release-upgrade` tool that upgrades your release (though other tools exist too). Use `man` to see the manual pages; but `dist-upgrade` is **not** used to bump you from one release to the next in Ubuntu as it can break the system  (the *release-upgrade* tools provide order to the upgrade ensuring an successful upgrade, and bypass pitfalls)

Answer (score 0):

turns out that the distribution upgrade process added a line *at the end* of `/etc/default/grub` which overwrites my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`.
I just had to scroll down to the end of the file to delete it.

Comment: Please read release notes & upgrade instructions before performing upgrades.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-notes/21951 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImpishUpgrades etc